# I tried to work with Cancellationtoken but it wont work

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

So basically I tried following some Tutorials und examples on how to cancel an Task.

- I understand, that you need a `CancellationTokenSource token` out of which you can extract a token that you need as an parameter (`CancellationToken token`) for the Task you want to stop

My **problem** is: when i press the "cancel"Button **nothing stops**.

Here is the general Code to that (I am using blazor Web Server)
.razor:

```
<Button Clicked="@StartTask"> start </Button>
<Button Clicked="@StopTask"> cancel </Button>  //onlyshown when task runs

@code{
    static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token; 
    
    
    public Task StartTask()
    {
       await DoSomeApiStuff(token);
    }
    
    public Task StopTask()
    {
       cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

.cs file:

```
async Task DoSomeApiStuff(CancellationToken token)
{
   if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }
    //Here is a really long Api and Saving in Database process
}
```

Do I miss something inside the Task I want to cancel?

Comment: You show code where you check the `token` at the start of `DoSomeApiStuff`, but do you ever check it after that point? You control at what points your method can be cancelled, by checking `token` at those points (normally doing `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`). If you don't check the `token`, your method isn't going to be cancelled

Comment: Click "cancel" before "start" and you will see the token is canceled. Because you only check the token on the start of ```DoSomeApiStuff``` and not when running your "really long Api...". Note: this API needs also to support ```CancellationToken```s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won´t work because you check your token only once. By the time you press the stop button the code has stepped over your if clause.

You would need to check the token more often while you do `//Here is a really long Api and Saving in Database process` or pass it to functions that support `CancellationToken`s

Comment: Aahhhh okay that was too easy to solve. I thought i did somethink with the token wrong. Thanks :)